# dilation operator on $L^2({\mathbb{R}})$ is continuous

Tags: wavelets

Prove the statement let $D:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $D(a)=f_a$  and $f_a(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}f(\frac{x}{a})$, where $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ then the mapping $D$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^+.$

Comment: Why is this tagged as "wavelets" ? Plus, you should show some efforts if you want someone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can approximate $f$ by a continuous function $g$ whose support is a compact subset of $(0,\infty)$ and it is fairly starightforward to verify continuity of $a \to g_a$. (The given function becomes a uniform limit of continuous functions).